# Prepare json file for GPT

Tags: python, nlp, gpt-3

I would like to create a dataset to use it for fine-tuning GPT3. As I read from the following site https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning, the dataset should look like this

```
{"prompt": "<prompt text>", "completion": "<ideal generated text>"}
{"prompt": "<prompt text>", "completion": "<ideal generated text>"}
{"prompt": "<prompt text>", "completion": "<ideal generated text>"}
...
```

For this reason I am creating the dataset with the following way

```
import json

# Data to be written
dictionary = {
    "prompt": "<text1>", "completion": "<text to be generated1>"}, {
    "prompt": "<text2>", "completion": "<text to be generated2>"}

with open("sample2.json", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(dictionary, outfile)
```

However, when I am trying to load it, it looks like this which is not as we want

```
import json
 
# Opening JSON file
with open('sample2.json', 'r') as openfile:
 
    # Reading from json file
    json_object = json.load(openfile)
 
print(json_object)
print(type(json_object))

>> [{'prompt': '<text1>', 'completion': '<text to be generated1>'}, {'prompt': '<text2>', 'completion': '<text to be generated2>'}]
<class 'list'>
```

**Could you please let me know how can I face this problem?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's more like, writing `\n` a new line character after each json. so each line is JSON. somehow the link [jsonlines](https://jsonlines.org) throw server not found error on me.

you can have these options:

1. write `\n` after each line:

```
import json
with open("sample2_op1.json", "w") as outfile:
    for e_json in dictionary:
        json.dump(e_json, outfile)
        outfile.write('\n')
#read file, as it has \n, read line by line and load as json
with open("sample2_op1.json","r") as file:
    for line in file:
        print(json.loads(line),type(json.loads(line)))
```

2. which have way to read file too, its [jsonlines](https://jsonlines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
   install the module `!pip install jsonlines`

```
import jsonlines
#write to file
with jsonlines.open('sample2_op2.jsonl', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write_all(dictionary)
#read the file
with jsonlines.open('sample2_op2.jsonl') as reader:
    for obj in reader:
        print(obj)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! Could you please let me know how to open the file using the first option? If I do this '# Opening JSON file
with open('sample2_op1.json', 'r') as openfile:
 
    # Reading from json file
    json_object = json.load(openfile)
 
print(json_object)
print(type(json_object))' There is an error

Comment: you are welcome! added read for jsonl file, in case needed for some use cases.